# How do you like to take / store math notes?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, education, lecture-notes

I always have difficulty with things like this but how do you like to take and store notes for later reference?

Paper and pencil? Physical books? Online notes? Where do you like to write them / upload them / store them?

Comment: This should be community-wiki.

Comment: Notes in relation to what? Notes while watching a lecture? Notes while reading something? Notes while doing research?

Answer (score 3):

Pen and paper.  The trick is that the writing reinforces the lecture, while typing doesn't.  It is always useful to remember that multiple repetitions help reinforce what is being said.

Answer (score 0):

I use an application called texstudio to write up my notes - so IOW, use LaTeX. It's a little bit difficult to begin with, but texstudio has very good facilities both to help with tex macros and for letting you compile easily as you work.

Comment: Where do you store your notes / how do you organize them?

Comment: @user525966 - with a textbook, I follow the structure of the book, which makes it easier to refer back to the text, especially if I arrange the numbering of sections after the same scheme as the book. For lectures, I tend to have a section/chapter per lecture, roughly. I've taken to use bitbucket as a repository - this works well, because LaTeX is reallt a kind of source code; that way I can easily share my notes or access them from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly and minimally

I must say don't agree with the rule that every answer needs to have 30 characters.